# syslog not logging my program log entries

Tags: c, linux, syslog, rsyslog

I tried logging from my C program, but I'm not finding anything entries from my program in /var/log/messages.  There are other recent entries there.

I'm using
Fedora 17:  Linux appliance.localdomain 3.5.3-1.fc17.i686 #1 SMP Wed Aug 29 19:25:38 UTC 2012 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux

I see this logging package installed: rsyslog-5.8.10-2.fc17.i686

```
myprompt: rpm -ql rsyslog-5.8.10-2.fc17.i686 | grep conf$

/etc/rsyslog.conf
```

In /etc/rsyslog.conf:

```
# Log anything (except mail) of level info or higher.
# Don't log private authentication messages!
*.info;mail.none;authpriv.none;cron.none                /var/log/messages
```

My code:

```
#include <syslog.h>
...
setlogmask (LOG_UPTO (LOG_NOTICE));
openlog ("m61", LOG_CONS | LOG_PID | LOG_NDELAY, LOG_USER);
syslog (LOG_INFO, "In m61_init");
closelog ();
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your log [priority mask](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/setlogmask.html) `setlogmask (LOG_UPTO (LOG_NOTICE));` discard log message bacause `LOG_INFO` priority level is below `LOG_NOTICE`.

[Priorities](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/syslog_003b-vsyslog.html#syslog_003b-vsyslog) in order of decreasing importance

- LOG_EMERG
- LOG_ALERT
- LOG_CRIT
- LOG_ERR
- LOG_WARNING
- LOG_NOTICE
- LOG_INFO
- LOG_DEBUG

[**About prioritiy**](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Overview-of-Syslog.html#Overview-of-Syslog)

> This tells how important the content of the message is. Examples of defined priority values are: debug, informational, warning, critical. For the complete list, see syslog; vsyslog. Except for the fact that the priorities have a defined order, the meaning of each of these priorities is entirely determined by the system administrator.

In your code change the value in setlogmask function or the priority level in syslog function.